# Order by children property in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

Is it possible to create a criteria that lists all objects sorted by sope property of their children?
For example:

```
class Post {
    User owner
}

Post.withCriteria {
    order('owner.registerDate', 'asc')
}
```

It fails with message: Error 500: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: owner.registerDate of: Post

What is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this isn't supported by grails out of the box but there's a plugin that enables this feature:

See http://grails.org/plugin/gorm-labs

Comment: Hm, strange. I've just found this code working. Am I using it right or am I really lucky to get it working way I need it? Post.withCriteria { owner { order('registerDate', 'asc') } }   This call gives me a list of all posts sorted by owner.registerDate... Maybe it's some new Grails 1.1.1 feature, while plugin makes it work for some <1.1 version?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible doing this:

```
Post.withCriteria {
    owner{
        order('registerDate', 'asc')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly what I wrote in my comment in the other answer 7 years ago.

Comment: Sure but the grails version is not specified. Should be fixed